# How to convert pixel value(R,G,B) to integer value?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

Example, I get the pixel value

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("Lenna.png")
cordinate = x, y = 150, 59
# using getpixel method 
print (im.getpixel(cordinate));
```

output: `(206, 92, 94)`

How can I convert `(206, 92, 94)` into one integer value (in Python)?

Just like the function [`GetRGB(x,y)`](https://dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-get-and-set-pixel-value-in-java) in Java and convert it back(integer value --> RGB --> setRGB value into image).

Comment: Your linked article explained the conversions rather well. What have you tried so far to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `struct`.

```
import struct
str='aabbcc'
struct.unpack('BBB',str.decode('hex'))
//(170, 187, 204)

rgb = (50,100,150)
struct.pack('BBB',*rgb).encode('hex')
//'326496'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the struct module, you can perform the calculations yourself:

```
def rgb2int(rgb): return (rgb[0]<<16)+(rgb[1]<<8)+rgb[2]
def int2rgb(N):   return (N>>16,(N>>8)%256,N%256)

rgb = (206,92,94)

print(rgb2int(rgb))      # 13524062
print(int2rgb(13524062)) # (206, 92, 94)
```